# Nested loop with range function in Python

Tags: python-3.x

While doing a nested loop using `range(5)`, why `01234` is not getting printed out.

The code I am testing:

```py
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(i):
        print(j)
    print()
```

The output:

```
0

0
1

0
1
2

0
1
2
3
```

Thanks and Regards,
Karthik Velu

Comment: insert your code, not screenshot of code

Comment: Hi @Karthik Velu. It would help if you considered giving feedback about the answers given to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have written range(5), means 5 values 0,1,2,3,4,
In the second loop maximum value is 4, ie ,0,1,2,3
So it prints that. If you want to print upto 4, change to range(6) not 5

Answer (score 0):

Try this modified version of your code:

```py
for i in range(5):
    print(f"{i}: ", end="")
    for j in range(i):
        print(f"{j}", end=", ")
    print()
```

The output is:

```
0: 
1: 0, 
2: 0, 1, 
3: 0, 1, 2, 
4: 0, 1, 2, 3,
```

With `range(5)` you loop over `0,1,2,3,4`. Thus, the second loop runs in the last iteration `range(4)`. Therefore the last sequence is `0,1,2,3`.

What you probably did not notice is that the first run of the second loop does not produce anything (because you try to loop over `range(0)`).